# Datanucleus 2.x AND Eclipse RCP 3.4

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, datanucleus

ANYONE using Datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/) with ECLIPSE RCP?

Eclipse DOES NOT recognize Datanucleus has a PLUGIN, with versions of DN newer than 1.1.0m3 :-(

The JARS i currently use, and the LAST ONES being recognized has plugins by eclipse (copied directly to \eclipse\plugins folder) are from datanucleus-accessplatform-rdbms-1.1.0.m3

Specific bundles:
datanucleus-rdbms-1.1.0.m3.jar
datanucleus-connectionpool-1.0.0.jar
datanucleus-core-1.1.0.m3.jar
datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.0.m1.jar

IS there ANYONE out there using DATANUCLEUS with ECLIPSE?

Thanks a lot.

marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marco,
You **know** there are other people using DN 2.x (or 1.1.x) with OSGi. You've seen their posts on the DN forum. You posted this exact same thing on Stackoverflow in January. If you actually look at your post from January you seem to be using JDO **2.2** (which is what was required for DN 1.1.0.m3), unfortunately that is NOT the dependency you ought to be using for DN 1.1.0.m4, or later. DN 2.0 requires JDO **2.3-ec** jar. This is all stated very clearly in the documentation 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/dependencies.html

and in the guide provided by another user of OSGi
http://www.jpox.org/servlet/wiki/display/USERS/HOWTO+Use+Datanucleus+with+OSGi+and+Spring+DM

The Eclipse log ought to tell you about problems with dependencies, and if it doesn't then that is an Eclipse OSGi bug since dependencies have to be fulfilled.

Comment: made it with the use of jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar

With this version installed in the Eclipse plugin folder, DN 2.x are recognized.

Thanks!